# UICollectionView.reloadData or UICollectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths makes cell hidden but still clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I got a UICollectionView with several cells in it.

I deleted the first cell by clicking a button on it, it works good no matter I choose `[UICollectionView reloadData] or [UICollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:]`.

Now the following cells will move forward, so the first cell now would be the second one before the deletion, easy to understand, right?

Now comes the weird part:

1. I click on the first cell's delete button, it shows:

   ```
    <MyCell: 0x7fc5de566590; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (220 20; 80 104); alpha = 0; hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc5de566740>>
   ```
2. I print the visible cells:

   ```
   < __NSArrayM 0x7fc5de655830>(
   < MyCell: 0x7fc5de55c060; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (20 134; 80 104); layer = < CALayer: 0x7fc5de55c210>>,
   < MyCell: 0x7fc5de635290; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (120 134; 80 104); layer = < CALayer: 0x7fc5de635440>>
   )
   ```

see? the cell I clicked on is actually that one been deleted, unless it's NOT! it has a `flag hidden = YES`, and it has a frame and superview also(yes the superview is the collection view).

Now that brings me problem because I meant to delete this guy MyCell: 0x7fc5de55c060.

So any clue on this? Thank you!

Comment: Are you reusing the cells ?

Comment: those cells were meant to be reused, right?

Comment: They should be reused, it's much faster and memory efficient. Although I don't exactly understand your problem. Do you delete a cell and the next deletion doesn't work ? How do you add the deletebutton ?

Comment: 1. I put a delete button on every cell, that's how I delete the cell
2. After I deleted the first cell, following cells will move forward
3. Now I try to delete the new first cell, however it is the deleted cell that catch the delete action. That cell has a hidden = YES flag, it is the weird part.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
It's because I override hittest in MyCell.
I didn't expect that deleted cells would still be subview of the collection view.